# JavaFX implementation of treeView inside a tableView

Tags: treeview, javafx, tableview

My problem is as follows:
 I need to represent data in a tableView but I need them to be grouped, sort of. Let's suppose there is a list of playlists which contain songs, so I want to display in a column theirs name, path in another and so on. Also, I want to be able to display each playlist's songs in the same manner underneath. It's something very similar to what treeTableView from JavaFX 8 does but I can't use it as I need that arrow for expanding the root item in a separate column where for the root item there will be that arrow and for the child items - a number corresponding to song's position.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the TreeTableView [treeColumnProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html#treeColumnProperty). Using that property you may display arrow in the column you want. To show numbers corresponding to the song position you may use [TableRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html) `setGraphic()` method.

Comment: I understand, this would be another question but just curious, is there a way to implement this in JavaFX7's tableView?

Comment: on the subject, how can I center the arrow?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible in default implementation. Maybe you should implement your own TableRowSkin

Comment: you're talking about the arrow, my second comment?